# Displaying data from Struct being passed around

Tags: c, pointers, struct

say, given struct:

```
struct someStruct {
 unsigned int total;
};

struct someStruct s;    // initiate an instance (allocate memory)   
s.total = 5555;                   // set a value

// and for    
void* cmd;       // local holder, which is a pointer (may be an argument of a function)


// at some given time
// format the designated pointer with a struct form(at), 'casting' the pointer
struct someStruct *cmd_ptr = (struct someStruct *) cmd;
cmd = &s;      // pass the specific address of the allocated structure and space to the pointer
```

How do we display the cmd.total value? None of these work.

```
// retrieve the data    
//printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (cmd->total)); // use designated pointer
//printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (*cmd).total);  // use designated pointer
//printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", cmd.total); // use specific address
//printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (&cmd).total);  // use designated pointer
//printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (&cmd)->total);  // use designated pointer
```

Comment: What use is the `cmd_ptr` variable? In the declaration you assign it to the same value as `cmd` which at that point is uninitialized and therefore have an undefined value, which means the value of `cmd_ptr` will also be undefined.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use

`cmd_ptr = &s;`

`printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (cmd_ptr->total));`

becuse cmd is void pointer and it can't display the unless you typecast it to someStruct

Comment: **Thank you**, Vijay. It works now. I should have used the other ptr. 

Now I can 


   // retrieve the data    
printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (cmd_ptr->total)); // use designated pointer
printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (*cmd_ptr).total);  // use designated pointer

    structCall2 (cmd_ptr);
    printf(" Struct contents: %d \n", (*cmd_ptr).total);  // use designated pointer

where 

void structCall2 (struct someStruct* state);

Answer (score 1):

You are using cmd for printing. Change the type of **cmd** to `struct someStruct *` or type cast to it.

**void pointer** has no type and therefore *does not know* how to perform pointer arithmetic to access the required field.

Comment: Funny enough, first to answer, even that a correct one. Then a down vote and a latter answer accepted which ironically has been given down vote by some one (though it is correct as well)

Comment: Yeah i noted that a while later. :) Some loony

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `cmd` back to someStruct:

```
((struct someStruct*)cmd)->total
```